# PHP WordPress the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

Where can I find the file where `the_content()` gets the value from `post_content` in the database?

I wanted to do the concept but with another content from the database,
So far, I've added a new column to the database ex. post_content2
How can I get its value by using something like

```
 <?php the_content2(); ?>
```

I tried looking at `post-template.php` and found the function but not how it gets the value from the database post_content.

Comment: `the_content()` gets the value from the `posts` table in your database (from the column titled `content`).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'll note that it's almost _always_ a bad idea to modify either core wordpress code, or core wordpress tables. Any modification to wordpress should be done through plugins or themes, otherwise you either can't upgrade wordpress, or upgrades will destroy your code.

Comment: Editing the wordpress table schema is a very bad idea - instead use a meta field

Comment: Probably something like https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ would save you a lot of effort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments above, and a more complete answer:

1. Do **not** modify core WP tables.  Either use [post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section) functions, or add a new table.
2. `the_content()` is just a convenience function that directly accesses the `posts` table, `content` column.  You can do the same thing at any time by getting the value from the database, and passing it through `apply_filters('the_content', $my_custom_content);`.  If you want to write your own `the_content2()` function, it could / should be done like so (using the `post_meta` method mentioned above):

   ```
   function the_content2() {
       // Global in the current post so we can get the ID
       global $post;   
       // Load your custom content
       $my_content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_content'); 
       // Echo it out (like the_content()) applying 'the_content' filters
       echo apply_filters('the_content', $my_content);
   }
   ```

If you want to figure out how to SAVE this content, then you can read this writeup:

[How to Create Custom Meta Boxes in WordPress](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/)

**edit**
It's worth noting that this functionality is already available in a few different plugins you can install.  In my experience [Custom Field Suite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/) is the most reliable and easy to use (but that's just my opinion).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but about the modification I did, will removing the column/row i added completely restore the table to normal?

Comment: If that's the only modification that you made to the table, then it should.